# JSON parsing not encoding string with underscore in Android using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to encode a string which contains a URL, I have a strange issue where the complete string is not being returned, I have noticed that it may be related to the underscore, I have tried a few solution where I replace the underscore, but haven't had much luck with that solution. Below is the JSON.

```
[{"id":"1","source":"BBC WORLD NEWS",
"time_date":"Sat, 25 Oct 2014 10:49:13",
"title":"Iran hangs woman despite campaign","description":"Iran defies an international campaign and hangs a woman who killed a man she said was trying to sexually abuse her.",
"link":"http:\/\/www.bbc.co.uk\/news\/world-middle-east-29769468#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa",
"image":"http:\/\/news.bbcimg.co.uk\/media\/images\/78529000\/jpg\/_78529517_78528720.jpg"},
```

I am trying to retrieve the image element from the json. The following is what I receive from my parsing.

`http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/78526000/jpg`

I am using this code at the moment:

```
String imageurl = feed.getImage();
try {
    imageurl = URLDecoder.decode(imageurl, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("---------------------------"+imageurl);
    imageurl.replace("_", "%5f");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

getimage method:

```
private String image;

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

private void requestNewsData(String uri) {
    RestAdapter api = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ENDPOINT).build();
    NewsAPI restapi = api.create(NewsAPI.class);
    restapi.news(new Callback<List<RssObject>>() {

    public void success(final List<RssObject> newsFeed, Response response) {
        Log.v("nas", "the webservice success " + response.getReason());
        for (int i = 0; i < newsFeed.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(newsFeed.get(i).description);
            newsList.add(newsFeed.get(i).description);
            FeederModel feed = new FeederModel();
            feed.setSource(newsFeed.get(i).source);
            feed.setImage(newsFeed.get(i).image);    // adding setimage 
        }
    }
```

The retrieved string is missing the final part of the url.

Any suggestion would be gratefully appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: image is a string why it's not surrounded by quotation marks? As in "http://..."

Comment: hi the json output is interpreted with [this interpreter](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your `getImage` method.

Comment: getimage method added to question

Comment: I need the place where you fetch the image url string. Also the *real* json would be nice, instead of the parsed one.

Comment: thanks .. question updated

Comment: Only now did I notice it's android-volley, sorry. This JSON Works fine in plain android though.

Comment: do you know how I can convert it to plain json. can you post some code for that or point me to the right direction . thanks..

Comment: I never used android-volley. Plain android* not plain json. Your json is fine. Only the code is doing something weird.